# Unmet dependencies on Ubuntu 19.10 eloquent

Tags: ros, ros2, apt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have spent a very frustrating afternoon trying to install ROS2 eloquent on a clean Ubuntu 19.10 VM without success.  The VM was fully updated before the install.  I chose the minimal installation as I only want to use ROS2 in the VM.

I started by following the installation instructions: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Linux-Install-Debians/.  I installed the keys and the `ros2-latest.list`file, did the `sudo apt update` and then tried:

```
$ sudo apt install ros-eloquent-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-eloquent-desktop
```

This format of command used to work on ROS but failed this time. Reading other questions, the following information was requested, so here it is.

```
$ uname -a
Linux andy-VirtualBox 5.3.0-46-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 17:37:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list
deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu eoan main

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=eoan
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.10"
```

After a bit of searching around, I read that each ROS2 release is paired with an Ubuntu release, so I tried the following command.

```
$ sudo apt install ros-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ros-desktop-full : Depends: ros-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-perception but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Finally, something that `apt` can install, but still no cigar!  I then spent about an hour trying to manually fill in the missing dependencies.  I ended up with this command:

```
$ sudo apt install -y \
>   ros-desktop \
>     ros-robot \
>       tf-tools \
>         python-tf\
>       tf2-tools \
>         python-tf2 \
>           python-rospy \
>         python-tf2-ros \
>           python-actionlib \
>           libtf2-ros-dev \
>   ros-viz \
>     ros-base \
>       ros-core \
>         python3-rosbag \
>           python-roslib \
>             catkin \
>               python3-catkin \
>                 python3-catkin-pkg \
>                   python3-catkin-pkg-modules \
>             python-rospkg \
>               python-rospkg-modules \
>                 python-catkin-pkg-modules \
>         python3-rosclean \
>         python-rosgraph \
>         python-rosmaster \
>         python-rosparam \
>         python-roslaunch \
>         python-rosmsg \
>         python-rosnode \
>         python-rosservice \
>         python-rostopic \
>         python-message-filters \
>         python-roswtf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
 python-catkin-pkg-modules : Conflicts: catkin but 0.7.18-1 is to be installed
 python3-catkin-pkg : Conflicts: catkin but 0.7.18-1 is to be installed
 python3-catkin-pkg-modules : Conflicts: catkin but 0.7.18-1 is to be installed
 python3-rosbag : Depends: python3-roslib but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3-rospy but it is not going to be installed
 python3-rosclean : Depends: python3-rospkg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Clearly, I'm missing something, but I have no idea what.  Any help would be welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350508/unmet-dependencies-on-ubuntu-19.10-eloquent/) by [Andy Blight](https://answers.ros.org/users/50920/andy-blight/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 19.10 is not a supported platform for Eloquent Supported platforms are listed in [REP 2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html) That's why there are no packages available. The first line of the tutorial you linked to is, "Debian packages for ROS 2 Eloquent Elusor are available for Ubuntu Bionic."

When you tried to switch to a non-distro based version you were starting to try to install [UpstreamPackages](https://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages) directly from the Ubuntu source repositories. Please see the discussion on that wiki page about mixing the sources which is giving you your conflicts.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-25**:
I've answered my share of these kinds of questions.

Clearly *something* is not clear enough when it comes to supported platforms/OS and the versions of ROS that can be installed on them.

**Comment by [Andy Blight](https://answers.ros.org/users/50920/andy-blight/) on 2020-04-25**:
Thanks for your answers. I don't know how I missed something that is now so obvious.  I guess I thought it would probably work anyway but clearly it doesn't.

Perhaps the line "Debian packages for ROS 2 Eloquent Elusor are available for Ubuntu Bionic." could be made bold to make it more obvious?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no Debian packages for ROS Eloquent on Ubuntu 19.10. The only way to use it on that platform is to build from source. There are instructions here: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Linux-Development-Setup/

The platforms a particular ROS distro supports are listed in REP 2000: https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#eloquent-elusor-november-2019-november-2020 . The table shows which platforms get binary releases and Debian packages.

Separately, `ros-desktop-full` is packaged by upstream Debian. It's not part of any named ROS distribution; I don't know if it's ROS 1 or ROS 2. There's more info about it here: http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andy Blight](https://answers.ros.org/users/50920/andy-blight/) on 2020-04-25**:
Many thanks for the tips about how to build from source.  I will try that out on Monday and see how I get on.

REP2000 is a useful page.  I have book marked it for future reference.